# Perl POST Automation and

Tags: perl, csrf, http-post

I'm looking to automate a quick script that will pull a bit a data from a financial data website called ycharts.com. A quick example would be pulling the P/E Ratio of Google for the first January of the past 3 years. I have already written the script for pulling the numbers, my problem is sending a POST request and having it return meaningful data. Here is my current program, built solely to pull the data, I can do the rest after finding the solution. (Also, this is not for profit, it's for my University research.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $url = 'http://ycharts.com/companies/GOOG/pe_ratio';
my $formdata = [
                pageNum => 1,
                startDate => 12/31/2004,
                endDate => 01/03/2013,
                ];

my $response = $ua->post($url, $formdata);
die "Error: ", $response->status_line, "\n"
    unless $response->content;

print $response->content;
```

But this is the content I get when I print.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>

</div>

<div id="explanation">
  <p><small>More information is available with DEBUG=True.</small></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've done a lot of research on the topic and can't seem to find the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated, but I don't want to waste anyone's time. (If this will take a large amount of effort to solve, please don't go crazy with a solution, just let me know and I'll accept defeat.)

Comment: Looks like you need to set the Referrer header at a minimum.  Found that on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672399/httprequest-in-perl-using-lwpuseragent-for-authentification-crfs-issue

Comment: I think you might be better off using WWW::Mechanize. It might help you get to the relevant stuff more easily. Also, use Firebug or similar to inspect the headers your browser sends when you change the settings on the page to those you want. It will probably reload, and send some more stuff, like a token. You need to get that token by loading the starting page first, finding the token, and then put it in your actual request with the POST data.

Comment: Looks like you may also have to first do a GET request, then use the cookies to set the request headers for the following POST.

Comment: "Perl POST Automation and" ... what?

Comment: @innaM - Get Firefox and Firebug, examine the cookies and headers in the requests and responses when you manually interact with the site.

Answer (score 3):

You have several possible problems with your program. Your program is not getting the data you need because of a wrong request; you need to POST to another URL. Also life is short, so use [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize):

```
use WWW::Mechanize qw();
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

# $mech->agent_alias("Windows IE 6");
$mech->get("http://ycharts.com/companies/GOOG/pe_ratio"); #receiving cookies

#don't use Regular expressions to parse HTML!
$mech->form_id("popupRegFree");
my ($csr_input) = $mech->find_all_inputs(name => 'csrfmiddlewaretoken');
my $token = $csr_input->value();

#$mech->add_header( "Referer", "http://ycharts.com/companies/GOOG/pe_ratio" );
#$mech->add_header(
#    "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
#$mech->add_header( "Content-Type",
#    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" );
$mech->add_header("X-CSRFToken", $token);

$mech->post("http://ycharts.com/companies/GOOG/pe_ratio/data_ajax",
    Content =>
      {pageNum => 1, startDate => "12/31/2004", endDate => "01/03/2013"});

print $mech->content();
```